# Magento 2 - Using UI Component as input for widget

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, widget, widgets

So far, in all the documentation and tutorials for UI Components that I've come across (Like the documentation here: 
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html, or in this sample module:  https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent), you can only create UI Components as a separate page/route in the backend.

I want to create a UI Component that functions as a parameter in a widget.  Is there a way to do this?  Specifically, I want to do something along these lines:

In widget.xml:

```
<widget class="MyWidgetClass">
    <label>My Widget</label>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="product" xsi:type="SOME_UI_COMPONENT">
        </parameters>
    </label>
</widget>
```

Is there a way to make something like this happen?  If I do create a UI component as a parameter, how do I get the parameter values to save in the widget?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Magento 2 module.
https://github.com/graschik/magento-2-admin-ui/blob/HEAD/docs/widgets/using-ui-components/README.md

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="example_widget_with_ui_components"
            class="Grasch\AdminUi\Block\Widget\ExampleOfUIComponents">
        <label translate="true">Example Of Widget With Ui Components</label>
        <description translate="true">Example Of Widget With Ui Components</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="component_data" xsi:type="block">
                <block class="Grasch\AdminUi\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Ui\Components">
                    <data>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">widget_example_form</item>
                    </data>
                </block>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/205995)